# Passing list element to function

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I have a module i've written that contains a function that collects a bunch of inputs, and appends them to a list. This module also contains a bunch of defined turtle functions that need to make use of the list elements. However, I'm getting a syntax error on the turtle functions. This is the exact function that gives me the error (the other turtle functions are similarly written):

```
def draw_circle(turtle, shape_info[5]):
   turtle.circle(shape_info[5])
```

List element 5 is the length input the user previously input in the first function. What am I doing wrong?

the error is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\ebarr\OneDrive\Programming\MIS 3300\MIS 3300\hw6.py", line 6, 
in <module>
import hw6util
File "C:\Users\ebarr\OneDrive\Programming\MIS 3300\MIS 3300\hw6util.py", line 122
def draw_circle(evan, shape_info[5]):
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: What is the error message? Please provide the full traceback.

Comment: What kind of parameter is `shape_info[5]` supposed to be?

Comment: Gotcha, will add it

Comment: it's an integer the user input previously.

Comment: Edit that information into the question, not in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a valid function definition:

```
def draw_circle(turtle, shape_info[5]):
```

What you *probably* wanted is this:

```
def draw_circle(turtle, shape_info):
    turtle.circle(shape_info[5])
```

Or maybe this:

```
def draw_circle(turtle, shape_info_5th):
    turtle.circle(shape_info_5th)
```

… and then call it with `shape_info[5]` instead of with `shape_info`.

Comment: Gotcha. So to pass list element number 5 to the function, in the initial def I don't also have to reference what list element it receives? just in the actual main part of the function?

Comment: @EvanBarre Right. The _parameter_ to the function is either a list (in which case you just use it like a normal list, doing `shape_info[5]` within the body), or just a single element (in which case it’s up to the _caller_ to do the `[5]`, not the function).

Comment: Gotcha. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

You would want to do something as follows:

```
# the function takes the list element type as the argument
def draw_circle(turtle, info):
   turtle.circle(info)

 user_length = 5; # index of the length in shape_info
 # we call the function using the indexed element into the list
 draw_circle(turtle, shape_info[user_length])
```

Comment: The input is initially assigned to the var usr_len, but we HAVE to put it and the other variables into a list, then pass those list values directly into the turtle functions to draw the shape.